# Вставить данные из MySQL в listbox

Tags: mysql, .net, winforms, c++-cli

Как вставить данные из БД в listbox не нажимая ни на какие кнопки, а при открытии окна?При открытии этого окна в форму под текстом "Выбор материала" должен загружаться список материалов из БД [image: При открытии этого окна в форму под текстом "Выбор материала" должен загружаться список материалов из БД]

Comment: Используйте событие [Form.Load](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.load?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Answer (score 1):

1. Подключаем Entity Framework для работы с БД
2. Превращаем нужный набор данных из таблицы в List/Array
3. Вешам на Form.Load, что он должен дёрнуть из контекста БД лист данных и отрисовать его

[Использование Entity Framework в C++ Cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35525222/can-i-use-entity-framework-from-c-cli-project)

[Типичные проблемы при подключении Entity Framework в C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571241/nuget-wont-install-entity-framework-into-c-cli-project)

[Русскоязычный гайд по Entity Framework, используя .NET](https://metanit.com/sharp/entityframework/1.1.php)

Comment: В вопросе нет ни слова про Entity Framework.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov пользователь является новым участником, в его вопросе был упомянут MySQL, если уж и давать решений так от и до.

Comment: Автор спрашивает, как сделать загрузку при _открытии_ формы, _не нажимая_ на кнопки. Ответ "от и до": добавить код загрузки в конструктор формы, переопределить методы `OnLoad`/`OnShown`, подписаться на события `Load`/`Shown`. И хорошо бы привести примеры кода по каждому варианту.

Comment: Почему вы упомянули _только_ EntityFramework? Если уж предлагать способы работы с РСУБД, то описать все _основные_ варианты: сырой ADO.NET (подключенный и отключенный уровни); микро-ORM: massive, petapoco, dapper; большие ORM: EF, linq2db, NHibernate... Вот это я называю "от и до".

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov с этим я соглашусь, моя ошибка, перепишу к вечеру ближе свой ответ